# На каком языке и каким способом можно сделать базу ФОРМУЛ по математике с поиском?

Tags: mysql

Нужно выполнить *примитивную* задачу: сделать базу формул с их описанием и примерами, добавить функцию поиска по ключевым словам. Какие языки можно применить и опишите вкратце метод или способ.

Comment: Да на любом языке. Зависит от того, где вы будете запускать программу, какой внешний вид программы вас интересует. Сперва отразите эти моменты в вопросе.

Comment: можно обычной программой для Виндовс. Какие методы решения предложите?

Comment: Можно на C++ или на Java. На Java для создания граф интерфейса можно использовать Java Swing(стандартная библиотека).

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

На Qt можно реализовать :3 
там  для работы с  **mysql есть модуль**  `#include <QtSql>`

таблицы прекрасно реализованы в виде **класса QTableWidget** в модуле `#include <QTableWidget>`

В QtCreator-e создавая **проект QtWidge**t можно "накидать" интерфейс через  дизайнер.

Также есть прекрасная русская документация  в виде книги *[Профессиональное программирование на С++. М. Шлее.](https://codernet.ru/books/c_plus/professionalnoe_programmirovanie_na_c_m_shlee/)*

---

П.с.

*Если у вас появиться вопросы то я могу помочь по реализации проекта :3   после создания вопроса добавь комментарий с таким сообщением

@[имя человека_которого_хотите_позвать]*